# How to move cv2.line up and down in detected rectangle to simulate face scanning in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, dlib

I need that one line moves up and down on the detected face rectangle. it looks like actual face is scanning. I would like to demonstrate GUI based scanning using python and opencv. I have tried the following

```
import cv2
img=cv2.imread("10.jpg")
cv2.rectangle(img, (60, 50), (140, 150), (255,0,0), 2)
cv2.line(img, (60,50),(150, 140), (0, 255, 0), thickness=3, lineType=8)
cv2.imshow("face",img)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through your rectangle height and draw the line in each iteration of the loop. To "scan down", iterate from `[0 ... height]` and to "scan up", iterate in reverse from `[height ... 0]`

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

height = 400
width = 400
image = np.zeros((width,height,3), dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(1000)
for line in range(height * 2):
    image[:,:] = [0,0,0]
    cv2.line(image, (0,line//2),(width, line//2), (36, 255, 12), thickness=2, lineType=8)
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.waitKey(2)

for line in range(height * 2)[::-1]:
    image[:,:] = [0,0,0]
    cv2.line(image, (0,line//2),(width, line//2), (36, 255, 12), thickness=2, lineType=8)
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.waitKey(2)
```

Comment: could you help me out to convert this code into wxpython code? @nathancy

Answer (score 0):

you can try to move the line in a loop from starting position to ending position.
I'll post my code but you have to adjust it for every face you detect. Have fun!

```py
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

#start position for y coordinate
start_y = 150
line_y = 150
#ending position for y coordinate
end_y = 50
#x position (bottom left and bottom right of the box)
x_left = 60
x_right = 140
#speed of scanning
speed = 3

#main loop
while True:

    #read frame
    ret, img=capture.read()

    #create bounding box
    cv2.rectangle(img, (60, 50), (140, 150), (255,0,0), 2)
    #draw a line
    cv2.line(img, (x_left,line_y),(x_right, line_y), (0, 255, 0), thickness=3, lineType=8)

    #x always stays the same for the line but y decreases so the line goes up (in opencv y goes from up to down)
    #speed makes the line go faster or slower (you can adjust it as you want)
    line_y -= speed

    #if the line gets to the top of the bounding box get the y value back to the bottom
    #of the bounding box so the line goes back down
    if line_y <= end_y:
        line_y = start_y

    #show image
    cv2.imshow("face",img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    #if press ESC stop everything
    if k == 27:
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```